# Android upload file to website threw html and php

Tags: java, php, android, html

I'm getting a error when trying to upload a file to my website through android.

Once I click on the photo i get this:
[image]

this is my Main.java

```
    package test.com.phonegap.app;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

This is my HTML file  Where everything happens etc etc etc

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Transfer Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for PhoneGap to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // PhoneGap is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {

        }

        function getImage() {

            // Retrieve image file location from specified source
            navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
                    alert('get picture failed');
                },{
                    quality: 50, 
                    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                }
            );

        }

        function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = false;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, "http://monaiz.byethost7.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
        }

        function win(r) {
            console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
            alert(r.response);
        }

        function fail(error) {
            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
        }

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getImage();">Upload a Photo</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my PHP file loacated on my website

```
    <?php
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/htdocs/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

Can anyone please give me a solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: what is being shown is the results of print_r($_FILES)

Comment: It's not uploading any thing to my website though

Comment: according to the $_FILES array, it is. have you looked for the  file name shown in the directory shown

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from your PHP code

> print_r($_FILES);

If you wanted to return if the file upload was successful or not you could do something like

```
$fileUploaded = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/htdocs/".$new_image_name);

echo ($fileUploaded) ? 'File uploaded' : 'Upload failed';
```